# Dropbox/MySQL+PHP Image upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, dropbox

I faced a problem with my Dropbox chooser and MySQL and PHP code, I am trying to choose a photo from dropbox and save the image into MySQL database. I can pick the image via dropbox and display it on my HTML page but I don't know how to save that image inside the database.

The code to for dropbox chooser

```
<script>
options = {
success: function(files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      add_img_to_list(file);
    });
  },




 cancel: function() {
    //optional
  },
  linkType: "preview", // "preview" or "direct"
  multiselect: true, // true or false

  extensions: ['.png', '.jpg'],
};

var input = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
document.getElementById("dropbox-container").appendChild(input);

function add_img_to_list(file) {



 var img = new Image();
  var src = file.thumbnailLink;
  img.src = src;
  img.name = "receipt_picture"

  document.getElementById("receipt_picture").appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

and there is my code to upload image to MySQL database via PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["button_add"])){
    $qry = mysqli_query($con,"Insert into table_project values('".$_POST["project_id"]."','".$_POST["car_name"]."','".$_POST["gas_price"]."','".$_FILES["receipt_picture"]["name"]."', '".$_SESSION["user"]."')") or die ("Cannot query with database");
    if($qry){
        $target_dir = "picture/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["receipt_picture"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

I would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you get any error or output?

Comment: When I select image from dropbox it is viewable on HTML page, but when I fill in my inputs and submit the thing image is not saved on my MySQL database. Did not get any error, just image is not saved.

Comment: It sounds like the Dropbox Chooser itself is working then, so I'm afraid I can't offer any insight. Hopefully someone else here can help.

Comment: Can you show us the form as specified in your HTML file? (Or does Dropbox take care of that for you?). Did you look at the following examples: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-383 ?